# What is the probability of drawing at least two yellow balls if you draw 4 times (without replacement)?

Tags: probability

14 balls total, 4 red, 4 blue, 3 green, 3 yellow. What is the probability of drawing at least 2 yellows?

My first take on this is to calculate 1 - the chance of not drawing a yellow in 4 pulls.

1 - (11/14 * 10/13 * 9/12 * 8/11)

However, I realized that this doesn't cover the case in that you can pull ONE yellow and still fail to pull another.

So, my question is: Am I on the right track with what I have done so far, and how do I take into account pulling just one yellow?

Thanks.

Comment: $\text{ P(At least two) = 1 - [ P(none) + P(exactly one) ]}$

Comment: **P(none)** you've already calculated. Favourable cases for **P(exactly one)** are (YNNN, NYNN, NNYN, NNNY).... Y - Yellow, N - not yellow.

Answer (score 1):

Split it into **disjoint** events and add up their probabilities:

- The probability of drawing **exactly** $\color\red2$ yellow balls:
  $\dfrac{\binom{3}{\color\red2}\cdot\binom{14-3}{4-\color\red2}}{\binom{14}{4}}=\dfrac{15}{91}$
- The probability of drawing **exactly** $\color\red3$ yellow balls:
  $\dfrac{\binom{3}{\color\red3}\cdot\binom{14-3}{4-\color\red3}}{\binom{14}{4}}=\dfrac{1}{91}$

Hence the probability of drawing **at least** $2$ yellow balls:
$\dfrac{15}{91}+\dfrac{1}{91}=\dfrac{16}{91}$

Answer (score 0):

14 balls total =  4 red, 4 blue, 3 green, 3 yellow.
Total no of ways of choosing 4 balls from 14 = C (14,6 ) = C(n,r) = n! / ( r! (n - r)! ) = 1001

There are only 3 yellow balls.
Total no of ways to choose 2 yellow balls from 3 yellow balls = c(3,2) = C(n,r) = n! / ( r! (n - r)! ) = 3
Remaining 2 balls can be choosen from 11 balls c(11,2) =n! / ( r! (n - r)! )  =55
Total no of ways to choose 2 yellow balls from 14 balls = 55 * 3 =165

Total no of ways to choose 3 yellow balls from 3 yellow balls = c(3,3) = C(n,r) = n! / ( r! (n - r)! ) = 1
Remaining 1 ball can be choosen from 11 balls c(11,1) =n! / ( r! (n - r)! )  =11
Total no of ways to choose 3 yellow balls from 14 balls = 11 *  1 = 11

Total no of ways of choosing at least two yellow balls = 165 + 11 = 176

Probability of choosing at least 2 yellow balls from 14 balls = 176/1001

Comment: That is too low: you should be looking at the number of ways of choosing $3$ yellow balls and $1$ non-yellow ball, or of choosing $2$ yellow balls and $2$ non-yellow balls

Answer (score 0):

Split up in $3$ yellow balls and $11$ non-yellow balls (the color of non-yellow balls is not relevant).

$$\mathbb P(\text{at least }2\text{ yellow balls are drawn})=\frac{\binom32\binom{11}2+\binom33\binom{11}1}{\binom{14}4}$$

Do you understand why?